# How to change Text based on specific URLs in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm  trying to develop a chrome extension for the first time and I'm having some hard time.
What I'm trying to achieve:
Every time a new URL reloaded, it checkes if it's one of the specific URLS I defined, let's say-
if reloaded URL = https://www.google.com/, change text to "This is google".
if reloaded URL = https://translate.google.com/, change text to "This is google transalte", and so on for 20 more urls.
When none of the URLS are reloaded, it will just stay in his last state.

Any help would be appriciated, thank you.

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
    </style>

</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="art.css"> <!--Include art.css File-->

<body>
    <button id="click"></button>

    <h1>H1</h1> 
    <h2>The Text I want to change</h2>
    <div class="square"></div> 
    <h3>by X</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {



    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {
        file: "art.css"
    });


});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "X2",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "X3",
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage" ], 
  "background": {
    "scripts": [  "background.js" ], //Background Scripts
    "persistent": false
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [ 
    "art.css" 
  ],

  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `background` section from manifest.json and background.js file.
2. remove `web_accessible_resources` section from manifest.json
3. remove `declarativeContent`, `tabs`, `storage` from `permissions` in manifest.json
4. replace `page_action` with `browser_action` in manifest.json
5. create popup.js and load it at the end of popup.html:

   ```html
     <script src=popup.js></script>
   </body>
   ```
6. popup.js will run each time the popup is shown, here's the entire file:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
     const url = tabs[0].url;
     const host = new URL(url).hostname;
     const text =
       host === 'www.google.com' && 'This is google' ||
       host === 'www.google.com' && 'This is google translate';
     if (text) {
       document.querySelector('h2').textContent = text;
     }
   });
   ```

The popup is a separate page so to debug it you should use its own devtools, which can be opened by right-clicking inside the popup, then clicking "inspect" in the context menu.